# Cannot install apk in one certain phone

Tags: java, android

When I try to install the apk on 5 different cellphones, one of them panics. The other 4 work fine. Here is the error info:

1. android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed adding asset path
2. java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10071 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Here is the detailed error:

```
04-07 12:10:06.788 9371-9371/? W/zipro: Error opening archive /storage/6365-3066/Download/qqmail/ISCAN-debug.apk: Invalid file
04-07 12:10:06.789 9371-9371/? E/PackageUtil: can not parse packag
                                          android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed adding asset path: /storage/6365-3066/Download/qqmail/ISCAN-debug.apk
                                              at android.content.pm.PackageParser.loadApkIntoAssetManager(PackageParser.java:898)
                                              at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseBaseApk(PackageParser.java:926)
                                              at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseMonolithicPackage(PackageParser.java:874)
                                              at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseMonolithicPackage(PackageParser.java:855)
                                              at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageUtil.getPackageInfo(PackageUtil.java:79)
                                              at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity.onCreate(PackageInstallerActivity.java:728)
                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6367)
                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504)
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:682)
04-07 12:10:06.789 9371-9371/? W/PackageInstaller: Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation
04-07 12:10:06.794 3635-3635/? I/WindowBlurViewManager: allowChangeBlurBackground
04-07 12:10:06.818 4402-4163/? W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10071 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
04-07 12:10:06.818 4402-4163/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1595)
04-07 12:10:06.818 4402-4163/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1627)
04-07 12:10:06.818 4402-4163/? W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:675)
04-07 12:10:06.818 4402-4163/? W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:675)
04-07 12:10:06.818 4402-4163/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.telephony.HwPhoneService.canReadPhoneState(HwPhoneService.java:969)
04-07 12:10:06.818 4402-4163/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.telephony.HwPhoneService.getUniqueDeviceId(HwPhoneService.java:984)
04-07 12:10:06.818 4402-4163/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.telephony.IHwTelephony$Stub.onTransact(IHwTelephony.java:364)
04-07 12:10:06.818 4402-4163/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
04-07 12:10:06.819 9371-9392/? W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10071 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
04-07 12:10:06.819 9371-9392/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1602)
04-07 12:10:06.820 9371-9392/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1555)
04-07 12:10:06.820 9371-9392/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.telephony.IHwTelephony$Stub$Proxy.getUniqueDeviceId(IHwTelephony.java:1297)
04-07 12:10:06.820 9371-9392/? W/System.err:     at android.telephony.HwTelephonyManagerInner.getUniqueDeviceId(HwTelephonyManagerInner.java:843)
04-07 12:10:06.820 9371-9392/? W/System.err:     at android.telephony.HwInnerTelephonyManagerImpl.getUniqueDeviceId(HwInnerTelephonyManagerImpl.java:340)
04-07 12:10:06.820 9371-9392/? W/System.err:     at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId(TelephonyManager.java:723)
04-07 12:10:06.820 9371-9392/? W/System.err:     at com.hianalytics.android.v1.e.a(Unknown Source)
04-07 12:10:06.820 9371-9392/? W/System.err:     at com.hianalytics.android.v1.e.run(Unknown Source)
04-07 12:10:06.820 9371-9392/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
04-07 12:10:06.820 9371-9392/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-07 12:10:06.820 9371-9392/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
04-07 12:10:06.820 9371-9392/? W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Any idea why it happens only on that phone? How to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: which phone is that??

Comment: @JimitPatel HUAWEI Mate 8, android 6.0

Comment: the generated apk is it a test apk or signed (release) apk?

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb It's a test apk

Comment: I had problem with test apk in the past as it crash after installing it on other devices, but not with the release apk, so I recommend you to generate the release apk instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 04-07 12:10:06.788 9371-9371/? W/zipro: Error opening archive
>   /storage/6365-3066/Download/qqmail/ISCAN-debug.apk: **Invalid file**

This is the problem.

According to the [Android source](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r5/xref/system/core/libziparchive/zip_archive.cc#236), a return code of `kInvalidFile` is reported in a couple of places:

- The archive (APK file) cannot be mapped into memory because the file is too big, too small or cannot be accessed.
- There's something wrong with the End Of Central Directory (EOCD) data in the APK file.

My guess is that there's something wrong with accessing the APK at that `/storage/...` location. Try moving the APK to the normal Android temp directory - `/data/local/tmp/`.

Failing that, there's either some corruption of the APK itself or some other software (Antivirus, Anti-malware, etc) is stopping the file from being accessed.

Comment: Hi adelphus, I've tried to copy the apk to different dir, still doesn't work. However, I can build and install the app into that phone through usb cable. So I guess no enough privilege to access the file is the case since the system is a customized marshmallow from HUAWEI.

Comment: The size of apk is 8.4Mb, neither too big nor too small. But still, how could I solve this problem?

Comment: @Rangtian how are you installing the App? The file has been copied to a location on the device, but how are you starting the installation?

Comment: I email the apk. When downloaded, the installation begins automatically.

Comment: @Rangtian that's probably why it fails. The APK is in a folder that belongs to the email app. I suspect the Huawei build (or maybe the email App itself) restricts the permissions of attachments so the package installer cannot install apps emailed to it - to prevent malware apps being installed by unsuspecting users.

Comment: I'm trying other potential solutions. Thank you sooooo much for your time

Comment: does anything worked for the problem as asked in question?

Answer (score 0):

This is because maybe u don't give checkself permission for marshmallow...try this:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
            1);
```

or use it like this on your oncreate:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},100);
                return;
            }
        }
```

then use this method:

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == 100 && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
        pick_file();
    }else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time :D  Let me try.